# How to structure a django model for user input when not all fields are required in all cases

Tags: python, django, model

I'm expanding an existing django application with new functionality. 
The problem is essentially as follows.

Sorry if the equivalent of this question has already been asked, I'm not sure what to search for to find the solution.

I have a 'store' model that contains a ManyToMany relationship to a 'departments' model, not all stores have all the same departments.

I need to track daily department volumes for each store, and I need a user form to enter all this information.

I don't know if I should create one model with all possible departments, or if I should create one model with one department and weight, and then create as many objects as departments for each day.

Scale ability in this application will be very important going forward, and I'd like to start right.

Code Below.

## Store departments

```
class Department(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.name;
```

## Volume Data Options (Model In Question)

Option 1, one model with everything:

```
class VolumeData(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(stores.models.Store, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=False,blank=False)
    produce = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,Null=True)
    dairy = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,Null=True)
    deli = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,Null=True)
    meat = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,Null=True)
    seafood = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,Null=True)
    coffee = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,Null=True)
    frozen = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,Null=True)
```

Option 2, one model but I need more objects.

```
class VolumeData(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(stores.models.Store, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=False,blank=False)
    department = ForeignKey(Departmnet, blank=False)
```

I feel like option 2 will be more flexible, but I'm worried about the number of extra objects it will create.

Option 1 however, will have a lot of nulls that I don't need, and I'm not sure if that's worse, it also bakes in the departments, which may be complicated?

The Department list won't be very dynamic, I expect to update it less than once every year, and it's unlikely that an end user will ever need to modify that information.

Comment: Option 2 is correct

Comment: With option 2 you should care about correct db querying using select_related or prefetch_related methods to prevent lots of db requests. This way django constructs SQL with JOINs instead of making db requests in loop for each related object.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Thank you both for your notes. I would up-vote if I could.

Comment: For anyone following up on this later: I went more or less with option 2, but I added a model to tie everything together to make queries easier. So VolumeData has a foreignKey to a second object, that tracks the store, date, and some extra meta info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like option 2 as well, but I think you need to go a bit further and create a class for different items that each department sells:

```
class Items(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_SKU = models.CharField(max_length=15) # set max_length as needed
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) # set max_length as needed
    number_sold = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,Null=True)
```

with this added depth of information, you'll be able to incorporate a deeper level of reporting, forecasting with AI, machine learning, etc. Just my two cents.

Comment: Would up vote if I could: Waiting on enough credit :D